# Error running testAction on CakePHP 2.4.6 error Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am attempting to write tests for CakePHP 2.4.6 controllers. I am following the documentation which suggests that I can use testAction to product output to test against.

```
<?php
App::uses('UsersController', 'Controller');      

class UsersControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase {
    public $fixtures = array(
      'app.user',
    );

    public function testIndex() {
      $result = $this->testAction('/users/view/10');
      debug($result);
    }
  }
```

When I run this test I receive the following error message:

```
UsersControllerTest::testIndex
Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR
```

Please can you advise what I can do to initialise the controller and gain access to its methods for unit testing.

Comment: will you post index method of UsersController ? problem might be there !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, it was in a custom authorisation component which was not included in the stack trace for some reason. It was attempting to use the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] which must not get set when testAction is called.